# iOS App Rejected Due to Learn More Link

Tags: ios

An app I recently submitted for the App Store was rejected, as it contained a "Learn More" button that linked to a site below the login button. This is a free app, but it is for existing clients of the company.

From Apple:

> 11.13 - Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes
>   to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
>
> We found the link "learn more" takes users to your website, where
>   pricing information is present and can indirectly lead to purchases or
>   subscriptions to an account, which users can access within the app.
>
> It is necessary to remove all links-out to the website from the app.

So, basically no links are allowed to the website for some reason. Does anyone have any ideas other than completely removing the links? I can't have a register button, because the manner in which clients sign up for service with the company. It seems a little ridiculous however, that the app can't contain any links to the site. I disputed, but was given the same answer again by Apple. Is the only option to create a form within the app and submit information natively, and not provide any information to prospective users/clients?

Comment: Try to put the link that do not contain any restricted information

Comment: Do what they say ? Or create a new page on the site to link to that doesn't contain pricing information.

Comment: try to display the page in a webview.
I had similar problem with google authentification (by safari), I display the authentification page in a webview, and the app passed the review

Comment: You have two options: do what they say like @CW0007007 suggested or make an appeal using iTunes Connect.

Comment: I already tried appealing but was unsuccessful. I will likely try removing the pricing information.

Comment: Think about what you want the app to be. It's a service for your costumers, not a direct way of getting new costumers. In that case, it doesn't matter if they can't get an account from the app (or see information about your company), because you are not expecting them to discover the app and become your clients, you are expecting them to become your clients and then install the app.
So just remove the Learn More button.

Comment: Basically the link is bypassing in-app purchases, you need to remove the link. Try linking to another page that is not related to payment. Or accept in-app purchases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Netflix app. It has a login form, and a "Forgot password" button, which asks for your email address. There are no links to the Netflix site that allow you to sign up. Even the big guys have the same restriction.

People need to learn about the app from your service, not learn about the service from the app.

Simply remove the link.

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing out-links and creating a form that submitted info to the website, but they still rejected the app. I ended up removing the "Learn More" button completely and it was accepted.